# Minix - Creating a stack trace in C

Tags: c, stack, stack-trace, minix

This is using Minix (http://www.minix3.org).

For a project for Uni, I am creating a stacktrace using an fkey. I have access to the process table and I am printing the Process Counter, the Stack Pointer and the Base Pointer. Now, I am stuck - I need to be able to print the names of the subroutines that are being called as I step back through the stack calls.

For example: I have the proc "getty", SP: 0x1669 PC: 0x41B0 BP: 41B4

My explanation:

SP is pointing to where the stack pointer is currently - somewhere in the execution.

PC is pointing to the next instruction to be executed and is incremented by one each step

BP is pointing to the top of the current subroutine

How would I go from these memory addresses to getting the subroutine names and/or how would I step backward through the stack?

Comment: check this might be helpful http://www.os-forum.com/minix/net/code-display.php?filenameid=15

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of typing "stacktrace" into the doxygen. Thanks :)